# NPM oracle package installation issue

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm

I am trying to install oracle package for nodejs.
It Keeps Giving me below error for C++ compilation.

```
    $ npm install oracle
    npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No README data

    > oracle@0.3.8 install C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle
    > node-gyp rebuild


    C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
      connection.cpp
      oracle_bindings.cpp
      executeBaton.cpp
      reader.cpp
      statement.cpp
      outParam.cpp
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): error C2632: 'char' followed by 'int' is illegal (..\src\statement.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'unsigned char' when no variable is declared (..\src\statement.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): error C2632: 'char' followed by 'int' is illegal (..\src\outParam.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'unsigned char' when no variable is declared (..\src\outParam.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): error C2632: 'char' followed by 'int' is illegal (..\src\reader.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'unsigned char' when no variable is declared (..\src\reader.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\rpcndr.h(178): error C2632: 'char' followed by 'int' is illegal (..\src\oracle_bindings.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle\build\oracle_bindings.vcxproj]
```

What can I do to get past this?

As suggested in comment I tried to install oracledb. Still running in same issue.

```
$ npm install oracledb
npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json test-seriate@1.0.0 No README data

> oracledb@1.1.0 install C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracled                                                       b
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_conf                                                       ig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\no                                                       de-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )                                                         else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable pa                                                       rallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  njsOracle.cpp
  njsPool.cpp
  njsConnection.cpp
  njsResultSet.cpp
  njsMessages.cpp
  njsIntLob.cpp
  dpiEnv.cpp
  dpiEnvImpl.cpp
  dpiException.cpp
  dpiExceptionImpl.cpp
  dpiConnImpl.cpp
  dpiDateTimeArrayImpl.cpp
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       326): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersis                                                       tent(const v8::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been d                                                       efined (..\src\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_mod                                                       ules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(319) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPe                                                       rsistent'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       346): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal(const v8                                                       ::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been defined (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb                                                       \build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(334) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' mus                                                       t be a type (..\src\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\nod                                                       e_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' (..\                                                       src\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle                                                       db\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb                                                       \build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\                                                       src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build                                                       \oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\src\                                                       njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\ora                                                       cledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       768): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads c                                                       ould convert all the argument types (..\src\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [                                                       C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *,                                                        const char *, uint32_t)'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       772): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v                                                       8::Object> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8                                                       ::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' (..\src\njs\src\njsP                                                       ool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracled                                                       b.vcxproj]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'                                                        to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object>'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p                                                       erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C2039: 'Use' : is not a member of 'node::Buffer' (..\s                                                       rc\njs\src\njsPool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracled                                                       b\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found (..\src\njs\src\njs                                                       Pool.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracle                                                       db.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       326): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersis                                                       tent(const v8::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been d                                                       efined (..\src\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_m                                                       odules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(319) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPe                                                       rsistent'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       326): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersis                                                       tent(const v8::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been d                                                       efined (..\src\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\no                                                       de_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(319) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPe                                                       rsistent'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       346): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal(const v8                                                       ::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been defined (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle                                                       db\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(334) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       346): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal(const v8                                                       ::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been defined (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\or                                                       acledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(334) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       326): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersis                                                       tent(const v8::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been d                                                       efined (..\src\njs\src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\nod                                                       e_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(319) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPe                                                       rsistent'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       346): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal(const v8                                                       ::Local<T> &)' : function template has already been defined (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\ora                                                       cledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
          C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\                                                       nan\nan.h(334) : see declaration of 'Nan::imp::NanEnsureLocal'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' mus                                                       t be a type (..\src\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\n                                                       ode_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' (..\                                                       src\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\orac                                                       ledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' mus                                                       t be a type (..\src\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seria                                                       te\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracle                                                       db\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' (..\                                                       src\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\                                                       oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\                                                       src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\bui                                                       ld\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\or                                                       acledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\src\                                                       njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\o                                                       racledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\                                                       src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb                                                       \build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       768): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads c                                                       ould convert all the argument types (..\src\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp)                                                        [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxpro                                                       j]
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *,                                                        const char *, uint32_t)'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' mus                                                       t be a type (..\src\njs\src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriat                                                       e\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\src\                                                       njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\bui                                                       ld\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       772): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v                                                       8::Object> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8                                                       ::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' (..\src\njs\src\njsI                                                       ntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracl                                                       edb.vcxproj]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'                                                        to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object>'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p                                                       erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' (..\                                                       src\njs\src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\o                                                       racledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       768): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads c                                                       ould convert all the argument types (..\src\njs\src\njsConnection.                                                       cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vc                                                       xproj]
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *,                                                        const char *, uint32_t)'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C2039: 'Use' : is not a member of 'node::Buffer' (..\s                                                       rc\njs\src\njsIntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracl                                                       edb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       757): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' (..\sr                                                       c\njs\src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\ora                                                       cledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       772): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v                                                       8::Object> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8                                                       ::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' (..\src\njs\src\njsC                                                       onnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\o                                                       racledb.vcxproj]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'                                                        to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object>'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can p                                                       erform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found (..\src\njs\src\njs                                                       IntLob.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\orac                                                       ledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\                                                       src\njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\                                                       build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C2039: 'Use' : is not a member of 'node::Buffer' (..\s                                                       rc\njs\src\njsConnection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\o                                                       racledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       761): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier (..\src\njs\src\                                                       njsResultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\buil                                                       d\oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       779): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found (..\src\njs\src\njs                                                       Connection.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\                                                       oracledb.vcxproj]
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       768): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads c                                                       ould convert all the argument types (..\src\njs\src\njsResultSet.c                                                       pp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcx                                                       proj]
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\singhal\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffe                                                       r.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8                                                       ::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *,                                                        const char *, uint32_t)'
C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\node_modules\nan\nan.h(                                                       772): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v                                                       8::Object> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8                                                       ::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' (..\src\njs\src\njsR                                                       esultSet.cpp) [C:\demo\test-seriate\node_modules\oracledb\build\or                                                       acledb.vcxproj]
```

Could this be due to the fact that it was unable to locate oracledb.vcxproj?

Comment: [node-oracle](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle) is no longer in active development; they recommend using [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) instead, which is maintained by Oracle themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for that issue was to shift back to nodejs version 0.12.7.

Answer (score 0):

As furydevoid mentioned please try using the official [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) package from oracle corp.